# MySQL: ORDER BY whateverField ASC [with row X put first]?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

How can I order my resultset but also have a specific row (with `fieldX = Y`) be the first one?

Comment: May you provide more information and also show full order by clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ORDER BY (fieldX = Y) DESC, whateverField ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select tbl.*, if(fieldX = Y, 1, 0) as custom_sort 
from tbl
order by custom_sort desc, fieldZ asc
```

Now whatever the fieldZ may be, the row with fieldX = Y will always be the first one in the resultset

Comment: that would work too, but i feel like Ike's solution is cleaner for this purpose.